# Get the first instance of a record based on the value of a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model

I have two models, one is `Repository` the second is `Photo`. A repository can have many photo's.

My end goal is to show a set of repositories and a display picture for each repository.

I want to do something like:

```
@repositories = Repository.limit(10)
repositories_id = @repositories.map &:id
@photos = Photos.where(repository_id: repositories_id)
```

However this will return multiple photo objects with the same repository_id and I just want the first instance.

Comment: Use `.first` at the end of the query

Comment: which one? the last? Cause that would just give me one photo object and I need 10.

Comment: You want the first instance.. Cool. First based on any condition or any random first... ?

Comment: First based on the lowest Photo id.

Comment: what is the DB client you are using Mysql ?

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Comment: The best suggestion is, you create a column for primary photo in the table user itself. If you do it, then you will help yourself not doing more work. sometimes architecture helps..  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to move your `Photo` lookup into the `map`. It won't be the most efficient query pattern, but on 10 Repositories, it'll be fine for a while.

```
@repositories = Repository.limit(10)
@photos = @repositories.map do |repository|
  Photo.where(repository_id: repository.id).first
end
```

Or if you set up `Repository.has_many :photos`,

```
@repositories = Repository.limit(10)
@photos = @repositories.map do |repository|
  repository.photos.first
end
```

---

**Update** with 3 queries instead of 11

```
@repositories = Repository.limit(10)
repository_ids = @repositories.map &:id
photo_ids = Photo.where(repository_id: repository_ids).group(:repository_id).minimum(:id)
photos = Photo.find(photo_ids.values)
```

Comment: That will load 10 Photo objects from my Db. Individually. I don't want to hit my Db 10 times for this query.

Comment: More efficient pattern added. I think you can do it in one query if you write it totally custom [using PARTITION or a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group).